# My Android Application Take Too Much Memory?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I've built a simple android program. The program uses an SQL database and has a lot of pictures.

When I check how much RAM my application takes, I see that it uses 4.5M the first time I launch it, and grows by something like 1M every time I exit it via the back or the the home button, and re-enter it.

My question is- is it normal for a program that doesn't do something complicated(a calculation regarding drinking and driving), that uses a database and has a lot of images, to consume that amount of memory?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to install this eclipse plug-in.  Great for tracking down memory leaks: http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: No Its not normal. Check if you are closing all database cursors properly. Can you share the code?

Answer (score 3):

They actually just published a post about tracking down memory leaks on the Android Developer blog a couple hours ago: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29

Answer (score 1):

I would say that's not normal. A program should not grow in size by 20% just from exiting and re-entering. I would look at what you're doing on exit and load, to see if there's something you're storing but not cleaning up.